# select prometheus alerts newer than a given time

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I am working with grafana, trying to show a list of pods that are triggering a custom prometheus alert.

This query do the trick:

```
sum(ALERTS{alertname="myCustomAlert"}) BY (pod_name)
```

The problem is, it list all the alerts, and don't seems affected if I change the time interval to see only the ones launched in the last 5 minutes, or last hour

There is any way to limit in time the alert list? Lot of thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That expression will produce the number of alerts by `pod_name` firing at the current time (just as you would expect `up{instance="foo"}` to tell you whether instance `foo` is up now, whether you're looking at a dashboard that shows the last 5 minutes or the last hour).

If you want to see the values change over time, you could e.g. graph it. Then you'd see it change over time. And when the alert started and stopped firing for each pod.

And if you want the value at some past time, simply set the end time of the Grafana dashboard range to that time. (E.g. if your dashboard was showing the time range between 2 PM and 3 PM on January 1st, then your query would return the alerts firing at 3 PM on January 1st.

Comment: _"if your dashboard was showing the tim range between 2 PM and 3 PM on January 1st, then your query would return the alerts firing at 3 PM on January 1st."_ => No, its not. I am working with an alert fired some hours ago, and if I select a time range in grafana "last five minutes" the list still is showed. Also, the metric don't have any "date" or "time" label to filter it for :(

Comment: It's not about when the alert started firing, it's about whether it's still firing now (or whatever the end of your selected range in Grafana is).